# (c++) Need help overloading operator+ for my class Polynomial

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So I am trying to overload the operator + for my Polynomial array, and I keep getting _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) error (line 52) and I can't figure out why.
The problem must be with the way I overloaded operator+ since it doesn't happen without it.

```
class Polynomial

    {
    public:
        int compo;
        int expo;
        int size; // array size + largest exponent
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&, const Polynomial &);
        friend istream &operator>>(istream&, Polynomial &);
        int* arr;
        Polynomial();
        Polynomial(int);
        Polynomial(const Polynomial&);
        ~Polynomial();
        int getSize();
        Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial &);


    private:


    };
```

...

```
Polynomial Polynomial::operator+(const Polynomial &p)
{
    Polynomial p1;
    for (int i = 0; i < p1.size; i++)
    {
        p1.arr[i] = arr[i] + p.arr[i];
    }
    return p1;
}
```

main (just for checking what's going on):

```
int main()
{
    Polynomial p;
    p.arr[2] = 4;
    p.arr[0] = 4;
    cout << p;
    cout << "Enter compo, expo:\n";
    cin >> p;
    Polynomial z;
    z = z + p;
    cout << z;
    return 0;
}
```

constructors:

```
Polynomial::Polynomial()
{
    size = 100;
    arr = new int[size];
}

Polynomial::Polynomial(int a)
{
    size = a;
    arr = new int[size];
}
```

Copy constructor:

```
Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial& p)
{
    arr = p.arr;
    size = p.size;
}
```

Destructor:

```
Polynomial::~Polynomial()
{
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Cin:

```
istream &operator>>(istream &input, Polynomial &p)
{
    input >> p.compo;
    input >> p.expo;
    if (p.expo > p.size+1)
    {
        int *temp;
        p.size = p.expo + 1;
        temp = new int[p.expo + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < p.expo+1; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = p.arr[i];
        }
        delete[] p.arr;
        p.arr = temp;
    }
    p.arr[p.expo] = p.compo;
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your constructor? How did you allocate `p.arr`?

Comment: You fail in memory management. You may replace `int* arr;` by `std:::vector<int> arr` (and get rid of `int size;`)

Comment: We haven't learned about vector yet so I am not allowed to use them :|

Comment: In `operator+`, you are creating default `Polinomial` object (how that creation is done - we are unaware of), and in the immediate for loop, you are looping through it's size (completely disregarding the sizes of your arguments, potentially going out of bounds on them). So, how those objects are constructed? How are they copy-constructed?

Comment: I added the constructors codes to the question, practically I am creating an array of 100 ints

Comment: Since the constructor that takes a size isn't used, the problem doesn't seem to be with the array management here. The big red flag here is reading that new value of `p` from `cin`, which relies on code that hasn't been shown yet.

Comment: So, since you aren't creating the `Polynomial` with custom size in your example, it isn't what causes the crash, **but still is a problem, that needs fixing**. I would like to see, how are your `Polynomial` objects copy-constructed/destructed.

Comment: @Dmitriy It's all in the code, that he pasted?

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius I am now adding both copy constructor and destructor

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius, It's strongly need to watch realization of copy constructor.

Comment: Everything is fine with the posted code, expect it's a dangerous one. Cin seem to be the problem, can you show us operator >> overload?

Comment: @Gil, So, please show us your copy-constructor/destructor, since you didn't.

Comment: You can't assign arrays my friend. Do it element by element.

Comment: @Dmitriy What? I don't understand what you want to ask of me.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius I edited the question, it's there now.

Comment: @Gil, after your update, your problem is clear. You are trying to delete the same array twice, since copy-constructor just copies pointer to the array location (not the array itself). You need to re-create your array, and copy it element-by-element, as Black Moses suggested.

Comment: @Black Moses I added the Cin

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius, I mean that his problem may be connected with heap/stack memory allocation for his objects. So, copy constructor gave me the answer.

Comment: @Dmitriy I am still confused, why you 1) asked questions, answers to which where present in the OPs question itself. 2) Asked any follow-up questions that you had, to me, rather than OP, since all information that was available to me, was available to you as well.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius, nevermind. I asked my earlier question in the time Gil haven't written code for copy constructor and destructor. After code renewing I deleted my first comment. )

Comment: Without a defined = operator, `Polynomial`is in violation of the Rule of Three. Read more here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: Thanks. So I fixed the copy constructor issue and added an assignment operator (which works great by itself), but there's still something wrong with the operator+, it doesn't crash anymore but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be problem with copy constructor.

```
Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial& p)
{
    arr = p.arr;
    size = p.size;
}
```

With this, you assign pointers, not arrays. Do it in a loop, element by element

```
Polynomial::Polynomial(const Polynomial& p)
{
    compo = p.compo;
    expo = p.expo;
    size = p.size;
    arr = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i< size; ++i)
        arr[i] = p.arr[i];

}
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting something? For example array allocation (i.e. `arr = new [p.size];`), and `size` initialization (i.e. `size = p.size`)? ;) Just noticed your last line: Copy-constructor is not an assignment operator. The object is getting constructed with it, there's no possibility of `them being different sizes`.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly the culprit. A suggestion to @gil: get rid of the constructor that takes a size. Don't put it back until you've got the rest of the code working reliably, then carefully look at all the code to find places that make assumptions about the size of the array.

Comment: I am getting into and endless loop while doing this

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - yes, that's necessary, but not for this particular example (which is the point of the comment that says "assuming array sizes are the same). One step at a time: dealing with different size arrays can wait until the base code is working correctly.

Comment: @PeteBecker as my comment-edit says: it is a copy-constructor, not assignment-operator, it is impossible for `them to be different sizes`, since the object, on which the constructor is being called, wasn't constructed yet.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I pasted the constructor code and added a line (size = p.size) and it goes into an endless loop for some reason

Comment: @Gil Which loop? That may, or may not be, different problem, to which your question is about, please clarify.

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. I will edit asap :) Now you shouldn't have endless loop.

Comment: I don't know exactly actually, I am getting an empty console for a sec and then it crashed

Comment: @BlackMoses it must have something to do with it because when I delete the use of operator+ it works

Comment: This is a great time for you to fire up your IDE's debugger and take a step through the code to see where it goes nuts. What development environment are you using, @Gil ?

Comment: @Gil Oh, probably it is because, you are assigning to an existing instance of `Polynomial`, not creating a new one, with the return value of `operator+` (when only copy-constructor will be invoked), you need to overload assignment operator (`operator=`) as well.

Comment: I did some edits and I keep getting the same error as I did to begin with. Even after fixing the copy constructor issue like you suggested

Comment: @Gil, As I mentioned in my latest comment, I just figured, that your program had 2 bugs, not one. 1st was related to your copy-constructor, and 2nd in your absence of assignment operator (since it is doing the same thing, as your program was doing before fixing the copy-constructor).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Just added an assignment operator, now the program doesn't crash but I get nothing on Polynomial z (main)

Comment: btw the assignment works great without using the operator+, so the problem must still be there.

Comment: Well, if you have operator= overload, this is next bug you are facing (operator >>). `for (int i = 0; i < p.expo+1; i++)` - temp are same sizes, but if expo + 1 is larger than size, then some "temp" elements are not initialized. `delete[] p.arr; p.arr = temp;` - you assign to deleted array (As I said you can't assign arrays, and more than that you can't assign array to deleted pointer)

Comment: @BlackMoses Fixed! Finally! the operator= had a tiny bug on it and now they are both working great, thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 1):

How to write an easy operator + in a polynomial-like class:

Step 1:  do not mix storage logic with other logic.  Storage is tricky enough.  Store your data in a `std::vector`, and use its size as your size.

Step 2: the rule of zero.  Either fail to implement, or `=default`, your move/copy assign and ctors.  Sometimes implement a dtor/zero arg ctor, but allocate no resources there: step 1 covers that.  (`=default` may not be needed, but sometimes it is.  Rather  than remebering when it is needed, just do it when you actually want the default xopy/move explicitly).

Step 3: Implement `operator+=`.  It is easier than `operator+` almost always.  It should be 4 lines long:

```
Foo& operator+=(Foo const& rhs){
  storage.resize((std::max)(storage.size(),rhs.storage.size());
  for(size_t i=0; i<rhs.storage.size();++i)
    storage[i]+=rhs.storage[i];
  return *this;
}
```

Code to trim leading zeros can also be added.

Step 4: Implement `operator+` as follows:

```
friend Foo operator+(Foo lhs, Foo const& rhs){
  lhs+=rhs;
  return std::move(lhs);
}
```

and you are done.  (replace `Foo` with your type name).  You even get highly efficient `r = a+b+c+d` out of it.

---

Your copy ctor may be broken, but I maintain your problem is actually that you *have* a copy ctor more than it having a bug in it.